# What does "$td" stand for in the documentation of PHP's mcrypt extension?

Tags: php, coding-style, mcrypt

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-module-open.php

```
<?php
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '',
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '/usr/lib/mcrypt-modes');

    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-256', '', 'ofb', '');
?>
```

In the documentation, it is described as an "encryption descriptor" in `mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size()`'s page, but that's as far as I got.

It's bugging me that it isn't `$ed` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Twofish Descriptor"?

Description

> This function opens the module of the algorithm and the mode to be used. The name of the algorithm is specified in algorithm, e.g. "**twofish**" or is one of the MCRYPT_ciphername constants. The module is closed by calling mcrypt_module_close().

Return Values

> Normally it returns an encryption **descriptor**, or FALSE on error.

Comment: In a book I'm reading they write $td, but use'blowfish' as a cipher. Also here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-enc-get-iv-size.php, the object is also called td.